How to push a GoRoute over a StatefulShellRoute?
I have the following router config
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> bottomHomeNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'bottomHomeNavigatorKey');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> bottomSecondNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'bottomSecondNavigatorKey');

final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/home',
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      redirect: (context, state) {
        // debugger();
        if (state.fullPath == null || state.fullPath == '/') {
          return '/home';
        }
        return state.fullPath;
      },
      parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
      routes: [
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          builder: (context, state, child) => MainPage(child: child),
          parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: bottomHomeNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'home',
                  parentNavigatorKey: bottomHomeNavigatorKey,
                  builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: bottomSecondNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'second',
                  parentNavigatorKey: bottomSecondNavigatorKey,
                  builder: (context, state) => const SecondPage(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: 'orders',
          builder: (context, state) => const OrdersPage(),
          parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: ':orderId',
              parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
              builder: (context, state) => SingleOrderPage(
                orderId: state.pathParameters['orderId'],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/splash',
      parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state) => const SplashPage(),
    ),
  ],
);

What I need is to have root page with BottomNavigationBar working with StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack.
But when I go to /orders, I want a new page over the MainPage, not replacing.
I tried to put GoRoute('/orders') into one of StatefulShellBranchs, but it just builds the orders page inside the MainPage. And I can't provide the rootNavigatorKey to it.
Can't figure out the way to make it work.

From my understanding of your question, you want to have a home and other pages with a nav bar, and then have pages pushed on top that don't have a navbar. If this assumption is correct I also had the same trouble. My solution is a bit hacky and it would be great to hear from some more experienced developers, but I just conditionally rendered the nav bar. All pages in my app are the same, but some call a function to remove the nav bar when they are rendered and then re-render the nav bar on exit. This was sufficient for my purposes. I accomplished this with a combination of provider and get_it (NOT GetX) but get_it should be optional. If you want to look through my code it is available here: https://github.com/nunibye/Eko.
